# Nested RouterPagerAdapter's not restoring state on rotation

Tags: android, android-savedstate, conductor

The root controller, which has a `RouterPagerAdapter`, hosts controller A which has its own `RouterPagerAdapter`.

Controller A1 is hosted by controller A

```
[ Root Controller ]
[   A   ] [   B   ]
[A1] [A2]
```

Upon rotation, Root Controller,  A and A1 receive their `onSaveInstanceState/onSaveViewState`, but neither A nor A1 is receives it `onRestoreInstanceState/onRestoreViewState`.

Why is this so?
What is the correct implementation to ensure that all children will have their state restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSaveViewState` will be called, but `onRestoreViewState` will not be called due to the `viewPager.setAdapter(null);` line.

The example in Conductor's docs sets the adapter to null when the view is being destroyed.

```
Override protected void onDestroyView(@NonNull View view) {
    viewPager.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroyView(view);
  }
```

Because of this, `RouterPagerAdapter` will call `configureRouter` to which the `router` does **not** have a root controller, and will `new Cont()`

```
if (!router.hasRootController()) {
      router.setRoot(RouterTransaction.with(new Cont()));
    }
```

Also note, when nesting a `viewPager` within another, both should have unique ids, else on rotation will overwrite the save state of the parent `viewPager`, and will show the wrong current item.